# HorizontalScrollView and RTL

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to use horizontalscrollview from Right to Left.
My targetSDK is 17.
I have inside the manifest

```
<application android:supportsRtl="true">
```

My layout is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@id/lay_main_firma_outer"
android:orientation="vertical"    
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"   
android:weightSum="1.0"
android:background="@color/bg_firma" >

<HorizontalScrollView 
    android:id="@id/lay_main_firma_hscroll"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" >           
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/lay_main_firma_objekti"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>    
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I add objects at runtime to the linearlayout. At runtime I also set RTL with

```
    private void rightToLeft_post17(HorizontalScrollView hscv){
    hscv.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);     
    LinearLayout lay=(LinearLayout) hscv.findViewById(R.id.lay_main_firma_objekti);
    if(lay!=null){
        lay.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);      
    }
}
```

but it is not working.
Any idea what might be wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you change the direction at runtime?

Comment: I gave up. I have many other problems and this is not the most important, for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to invalidate your layout:

```
if(lay!=null){
    lay.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL); 
    lay.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: I have tried it, but does not working. I will try to get a real device, since I am using only emulator for above v17 and I do not have experience if this might be related.

Answer (score 0):

First, hide your parent layout of horizontalscrollview before loading the items in horizontalscrollview.

```
       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:id="@id/lay_main_firma_outer"
           android:orientation="vertical"    
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"   
           android:weightSum="1.0"
           android:setVisibility="gone"
           android:background="@color/bg_firma" >
```

When the uploading gets done,then programatically make your linearlayout visible like this:

```
             findViewById(R.id.lay_main_firma_outer).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```